# How to use the Visual Studio Code way of writing HTML tags in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Typing 'h1' in Visual Studio Code and pressing Enter generates <h1></h1>

But in Visual Studio 2019, I have to type <h1> in .cshtml file to generate <h1></h1>

How do I use the former way in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: You are referring to emmet anotation. Maybe you could search by that term in Google. Here is VS Code emmet doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andreas Gardiol, the Emmet plugin can be found on https://emmet.io/

But the plugin is not available for Visual Studio 2019.

I found it's port for Visual Studio 2019 from https://github.com/sergey-rybalkin/emmet.net/

Installed and it works great!